# Accessing other XML value from YUIBuild file

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, msbuild, yui

I have integrated YUI MSBuild for minification process. In the Build xml file defined for YUI i want to access other property from a xml file.

I have the version number defined in a xml file located in the project

```
<add key="VersionNumber" value="1000"/>
```

Assuming i have the above key in a sample.xml how can i access it from MSBuild project file

can i do something like this

```
<ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="constants.xml"/>
</ItemGroup>

Message Text="The output file value @(VersionNumber)"/>
```

any help will be aprpeciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution for this and thought it will be helpful to post. I used the xml read and got it , i used http://msbuildtasks.tigris.org/

sample code , but my code is different though

```
 <XmlRead 
  XPath="/add/@connectionString"
  XmlFileName="app.config">
    <Output TaskParameter="Value" PropertyName="MyConnectionString" />
</XmlRead>
<Message Text="MyConnectionString: $(MyConnectionString)"/>
```